# Add more field to json file using JQ

Tags: json, bash, jq

I would like to fill a JSON file, that is still empty with the below values using JQ.

I tried this code:

```
 echo '{"Name": "FileName", "Size": "FileSize", "Action": "Action taken"}' | jq file.json
```

But it failed:

> jq: error: clear/0 is not defined at , line 1:
>   clear.json
>   jq: 1 compile error

```
 [
   // Data should goes here
 ]
```

Expecting result:

```
 [
      {
       "Name": "FileName",
       "Size": "FileSize",
       "Action": "Action taken",
      },

      // and so on
 ]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're saying you have a JSON array in a file, and you want to append an object ot it?

Comment: @thatotherguy: I am not familiar with json and jq, I am looking for a better way to append data

Comment: What is the contents of `clear.json` currently?

Comment: The content is empty, I would like to add data like above

Comment: Is the file empty, or does the file contain `[ ]`?

Comment: No empty, and I would like to add some data, if `[ ]` is not useful, I can remove it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having trouble understanding the details of your question, but it sounds like you have:

- A JSON string representing an object, e.g. `'{"foo": "bar"}'`
- A JSON file that contains either

  - Nothing (the file is empty and therefore not valid JSON)
  - A JSON array, e.g. `[{"a": "b"}, {"c": "d"}]`

And you want to append the JSON object to the existing array, or if the file is empty, create a new array with the object as its own element.

The easiest way to do this is to first make sure the file contains valid JSON by writing an empty array to if it's empty, and then unconditionally append to that list:

```
file='myfile.json'
object='{"Name": "FileName", "Size": "FileSize", "Action": "Action taken"}'

# Check if file is empty
if ! [ -s "$file" ]
then
  # It is. Write an empty array to it
  echo '[]' > "$file"
fi

# Read from the file, append the object, write to a temporary file
jq --argjson x "$object" '. += [$x]' < "$file" > tmp.json

# Overwrite the original file with the temporary one
mv tmp.json "$file"
```

If you start with an empty file (or no file), after successfully running, the file would contain this:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "FileName",
    "Size": "FileSize",
    "Action": "Action taken"
  }
]
```

If you run it one more time, it would contain this:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "FileName",
    "Size": "FileSize",
    "Action": "Action taken"
  },
  {
    "Name": "FileName",
    "Size": "FileSize",
    "Action": "Action taken"
  }
]
```

Comment: How about if keys remain the same and each time I would like to make an entry, values are variables `Name: pic1.jpg, Size: 20KB, Action: Delete` and another entry `Name: pic2.png, Size: 75KB, Action: Keep`

Comment: In this case you can do `jq --arg name "pic1.png" --arg size "20kb" '. += [{"Name": $name, "Size": $size}]' < myfile.json`